# Exchange 2016 Server rule to handle misspelled email address

Tags: email, exchange, rules

We have installed Exchange Server 2016. I would like to make a rule to retranslate all emails that were send with incorrect name but with correct domain name.

Sometimes people make mistakes and send mail to jon@mydomain.com but not to john@mydomain.com for example. So I need a rule that will retranslate these emails to moderator's mail-box. Is it possible in Exchange Server 2016 Standard?

Comment: Why do you want to use a rule, instead of an alias? Give each user an alias email address if they want to receive mail at additional addresses. If someone sends an email to a non-existent address your exchange server should be configured to reject the mail and the sender will receive an NDR. So these types of issues really aren’t issues at all.

Answer (score 2):

Exchange doesn't support any sort of rule that would work in the way you describe. Instead, you should create alias email addresses for the users that experience common mis-spellings of their correct address. You can assign the alias to the correct user's mailbox, or to any mailbox you wish.

This is simple to do via the Exchange shell. For example, to add the alias `dan.jump@northamerica.contoso.com` to Dan Jump's mailbox, run:

```
Set-Mailbox "Dan Jump" -EmailAddresses @{add="dan.jump@northamerica.contoso.com"}
```

More information about adding SMTP alias addresses can be found [on TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123794(v=exchg.160).aspx).

Alternately, you may be interested in what's known as a *catch-all* mailbox. If configured, the mailbox will receive massages sent to any address in your domain that doesn't otherwise match a valid address. You can read more about this [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691132(v=exchg.141).aspx). However, this does not let you employ rules as you have requested, and you will likely receive **lots** of unwanted spam in this mailbox, making it difficult to find legitimate email. Therefore it is a less-preferred method compared to creating alias addresses.